# Overriding Internal CSS

Tags: html, css

Why external CSS doesn't override internal CSS in this case?

```
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Colors :: Home</title>
  <style>
  article {
    background-color: pink;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
  }
  .alerts {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  a h3 {
    border-bottom: 2px black dashed;
  }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main-cascade.css">
</head>
```

As you can see there is pink for background color in here. Assume that there is green for background color in the main-cascade.css (external css) at this case what prevents the external css to override the internal css?

Comment: Try using !important in the external css?

Comment: "what prevents the external css to override the internal css" — Nothing obvious. Maybe something is preventing the external CSS from loading at all. Maybe there is an error in the external CSS.

Comment: The duplicate doesn't fit, that is about overriding style attributes not style elements. I won't vote to reopen the question though: It should be closed as there isn't enough information to debug it.

Comment: @BeerusDev — Unless the external CSS has a `*` selector, then whatever selector is used will be at least as specific as the one it is overriding, so that shouldn't make a difference.